# How to retrieve a form from processFrom into an other action?

Tags: php, forms, symfony1

I want to retrieve data from my first form into my function `executeAddDomaines` to use these into a second form called by this function but when i give $form in parameters to this function i have this error :

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to domaineActions::executeAddDomaines() must be an instance of sfForm, none given, called in /home/webs/extranet100p100.net/htdocs/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/action/sfActions.class.php on line 60 and defined in /home/webs/extranet100p100.net/htdocs/apps/backend/modules/domaine/actions/actions.class.php on line 206

**This is my code:**

```
protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
{
$name = $form->getName();

$form->bind($request->getParameter($name), $request->getFiles($name));

if($form->isValid())
{

    if($form->isNew())
        {   
        $this->executeAddDomaines($request, $form);
        $this->redirect('@add_domaines');

         }
[...]
}

public function executeAddDomaines(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
{       

      $name = $form->getName();

      $params = $request->getParameter($name);

      $this->list_domaines = $params;


      $this->form = new AddDomainesForm();


      $this->setTemplate('listDomaines');
}
```

So how i can do it ?

Thank you :)

Comment: do you call executeAddDomaines on other places? Cause your error tells you you call it without the second parameter. something `this->executeAddDomaines($request)` instead of `$this->executeAddDomaines($request, $form);`

Comment: No. Ok but if i do `this->executeAddDomaines($request)` when i can retrieve my date from my first form ?

Comment: you can not call `this->executeAddDomaines($request)` the second parameter is required.

Comment: if i put the second paramater, $form, i got the error

Comment: You are redirecting the first action to the second action. You will lose the form data on the redirect.

Comment: @costa : So how i can do to don't lose data on the redirect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to save the form data in session and then get it in the 2nd action.

Try this (i didn't test):

```
protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
    {
    $name = $form->getName();

    $form->bind($request->getParameter($name), $request->getFiles($name));

    if($form->isValid())
    {

        if($form->isNew())
            {   
            # Replaced
            $request->setAttribute("form", $form);
            $this->redirect('@add_domaines');

             }
    [...]
    }

    public function executeAddDomaines(sfWebRequest $request)
    {      
          # Added
          $form = $request->getAttribute("form");

          $name = $form->getName();

          $params = $request->getParameter($name);

          $this->list_domaines = $params;


          $this->form = new AddDomainesForm();


          $this->setTemplate('listDomaines');
    }
```

After use it, you can clean the attribute form from the request